# Speed and I are related, although distantly

Tags: riddle

> I am one, my twin is another
>   Moving along, you might see either of us
>   Although which one you see, depends on where you look
>   Only at night are we truly very vivid
>
> Speed and I are related, although distantly
>   But not as distant as you think, as you see me often enough
>   My twin can show you the way, but I certainly cannot.
>   For every which way you look, I face the other way
>
> I am a something you must name specifically,
>   And my twin is another you must name too

**What am I? What about my twin?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing, that you are:

> **HEADLIGHTS** and **TAILLIGHTS**

I am one, my twin is another
Moving along, you might see either of us
Although which one you see, depends on where you look

> Depending on whether you look at the cars ahead of you, or behind you, or in the opposite lane, you'll see either headlights or taillights

Only at night are we truly very vivid

> Although they can be seen in daytime as well, they truly 'light up' at night

Speed and I are related, although distantly
But not as distant as you think, as you see me often enough

> You can gauge the speed of a vehicle at night based on its lights
>  The vehicle's speed is also determined at night by the throw of its headlights (i.e. don't drive faster than you can see)
>  On bicycles with dynamo-driven headlights, the brightness of the headlight is proportionate to the speed of the bicycle
>  Further, as pointed out by NL628 via a comment (thanks NL628!), if the car is braking, the taillight would be red, so if you brake, the red color appears.

My twin can show you the way, but I certainly cannot.
For every which way you look, I face the other way

> Headlights are used to illuminate the path ahead, i.e. the path of travel
>  Taillights illuminate you for the cars behind (i.e. the other way)

I am a something you must name specifically,
And my twin is another you must name too

> Hence my answer that you're the headlights and taillights on a vehicle.

Comment: Wow nice I was thinking red and yellow b/c of what you said, but this is basically the same!

Comment: For the speed and I are related part I was thinking gung vs gur pne vf oenxvat, gur gnvyyvtug jbhyq or erq, fb vs lbh oenxr, gur erq pbybe nccrnef.

Comment: Yes @Nl628 that is closer to my original thinking, but Phylyp is essentially correct.

Comment: Nice one @NL628 , let me add that in. Thank you, Lifesaving Linen!